# How to resolve XML/XSD schemaLocation attribute to read from database with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, xmlcatalog

I'm using Nokogiri gem. When it validates an xml, it reads the related schemas from local filesystem (in my case).

Is it possible to intercept reading of noNamespaceSchemaLocation/schemaLocation to supply them by my own way (e.g. from a database) ? Thanks.